# Is downvoting a question because you don't like the subject against the rules?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Not that I would ever do this, but I'm just wondering hypothetically...say you have a dislike for a particular subject, for example group theory. Is it against the rules to downvote a question regarding group theory simply because you dislike the topic?

Comment: *Disliking* a mathematical subject is an odd notion to me (*not liking* it is another matter).

Comment: Maybe not "dislike for a subject".  But downvoting because of the subject can be seen, for example a subject that should (in your opinion) be elsewhere and not in math.se .

Comment: @GEdgar The situation you mention is probably off-topic since the question seems to be concerned with *mathematical* subjects (as witnessed by the example in the question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is certainly discouraged.

However, we don't have many hard rules when it comes to voting; mostly just not to serially vote (up or down) a specific user. I don't think I can quite say it's against the rules, because I don't think any of the moderators would take any action against someone for such behavior (and a rule isn't really a rule unless there is some penalty for breaking it).

That being said, downvoting in such a manner in combination with other mean-spirited behavior could easily lead to a suspension for being "Abusive to others", one of our standard reasons for issuing suspensions.

Answer (score 14):

That would not be well-received on the main site, although something like it could be standard on Meta.

On Main, downvoting is interpreted as "this is a bad/poorly researched/unclear/unconstructive question."  On Meta, downvoting a question could mean "I don't think this question should have been raised," "I disagree with the conclusion the author is suggesting," or a [host of other reasons, most context-dependent](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/718/what-does-it-mean-to-downvote-a-question-on-meta).